# How to read data from mongodb atlas from pyspark?

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

I am trying to read data from mongodb atlas from pyspark but it is throwing an error.
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o204.load.

```
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid uri: 'mongodb+srv:<url>
```

**I believe this is throwing an Invalid url due to srv along mongodb.**

I want to provide jars required for connection using --jars instead --packages as --packages will trigger run time download of required connector .

Comment: Were you able to make it work? I get error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/model/changestream/FullDocument`

Answer (score -1):

With pyspark you can either set up a shell with the proper configuration or set the connection with python code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pymongo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.\
builder.\
appName("pyspark-notebook2").\
config("spark.executor.memory", "1g").\
config("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/database.recipes").\
config("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/database.coll").\
config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.0").\
getOrCreate()

    logger = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j
    logger.LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(logger.Level.FATAL)

    
    # read from MongoDB collection
    df = spark.read.format("mongo").load()
```

Comment: what is use of pymongo here ? my main question was how to connect mongo+srv not only mongo.